# Coupled incomplete graph cost estimation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, machine-learning, random-graphs

I have this very specific problem and I didn't find anything searching, so I apologize if the question is trivial. Also, graph theory is not really my thing so I could miss important points.

That being said, I have the following problem. I have a directed graph $G_1$, with $N$ nodes, completely connected, so with $2N^2$ edges. Each edge has a cost assigned to it. I have complete knowledge of this graph, so I know all nodes, edges and costs. Then, I have a second graph $G_2$ which has the same nodes and edges, but with different costs which are only partially known. My objective is to estimate the costs of edges in $G_2$. I assume there is some kind of correlation between the costs of edges in $G_1$ and $G_2$, which I would like to take into account in the cost estimation.

Of course, the trivial case is the one in which I have no knowledge of $G_2$. In this case, the only reasonable thing would be to assign the same costs I observe in $G_1$ to the edges. Suppose now that I observe the real values of an edge of $G_2$. I would like to adapt my expectation of the other costs considering this new observation.

Is there some well-known algorithm for this "paired graph" problem that I am missing, or any resource that could help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could formulate this as a graph edit distance problem, where you would set the cost of edge substitution as a distance between your weights if the edge weight is known, and 0 if the edge weight is unknown. Then for all unknown edges, you could assign the weight of the associated edge, or some other kind of reconstruction.
However, if there are many possibilities to match the graph, you will orient your reconstruction for just one of these matches, so maybe this is not what you are looking for...

Comment: Could you say a bit more about your assumptions on the correlation between the two graphs. Also, what would you consider a good estimation of the costs in $G_2$ i.e. what kind of metric are you using to evaluate solutions to this problem?

Comment: As currently stated, the graph structure isn't being used at all. You have a sequence of known values $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m$ (the weights of edges in the first graph), another sequence of partially-known values $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_m$ (the weights of edges in the second graph), and you are trying to use the observed relationship between $x_i$ and $y_i$ (in the cases where $y_i$ is known) to fill in the unknown values. It doesn't seem relevant which edges share endpoints.

Comment: @MishaLavrov This is true only if we already have the information of which vertex is associated with which vertex. If not, in the case where all weights are known, we would end up trying to match the weights in the best possible way, which is related to graph edit distance, so the structure of the graph is important...

Comment: @caduk The question says that the second graph has the same nodes and edges, in which case we don't need to do that, but it's possible that the question should be clarified...

Comment: @MishaLavrov Ah, yes, I interpreted it as the other graph is also fully connected, but you are probably right. If so, my first comment has no meaning.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you trying to estimate the weights of G2 in order to maximize the (Pearson) correlation between G1 and G2?